# get previous commit that got deleted on git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, github, version-control

Yesterday when I was at work, I was working on my project that i have on my home computer. The problem was when I tried cloning the repo it eclipse would crash. So instead I downloaded it manually and initialized the repo and then force pushed to my home computer. This deleted all the history and files in on the repo. I did some googling and tried reverting the commit but it the force push erased the commit history so I can only go back to the force push commit.

I have a computer at home which hasn't pulled the updates since this mistake and I was able to get its commit SHA. I used that on the web and found the last version its still there but I can't pull that commit because it got "deleted" and won't show in the repos history. Is there a way I can use the SHA from the last good commit and make that the master branch restoring my history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing the `HEAD` (the working position in the git repository), it tracks your history in the `reflog`. Executing `git reflog` in the command line will show your complete history. You can read more about it on [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

When you have the desired commit SHA, you can do a git checkout with it. Executing `git checkout [SHA1]` will take you to the desired position in the git history. From there, you can make a new branch from it by running `git checkout -b "new_branchname"`.

If you want to set your current branch to the commit, you can run `git reset --hard [SHA1]`. This would reset the current branch, but the previous state can however be found in the reflog.

Comment: when I do git checkout [the good sha1 that I want to revert to] it says reference is not a tree

Comment: If you cannot checkout the commit SHA, it indicates that the commit isn't stored in your local git repository. You can therefore upload it to central repository (I assume you use something like github), from your other computer. When have checked out the commit/branch on the machine you have it on, you create a new branch via `git checkout -b "backup_branch"`. Then you push it to the central repository via git push.

On the other computer you then run `git pull`, to fetch the new changes. Then `git checkout "backup_branch"`. You should now have checked out the desired commit.

Comment: alright I think I understand what you are saying. So from the computer I have at home that has the good commit I should make that another branch then from my work place pull that branch and it will fix the issue and I will get back my history?

Answer (score 0):

I do NOT recommend doing this as general practice BUT...You should be able to force push from the other computer, thus resetting the repo to its former state. Providing you don't want to keep anything you did while making a giant mess of your git repo yesterday.

Comment: yeah I don't care about the work I did yesterday I can easily rewrite it. Do you think force pushing will bring back the history I had on the git repo?

Comment: A simplified way to say this is : if you force push from the repository in the state you want to propagate it will basically "throw away" whatever is on the repo and replace it with what you have locally. ... so yes.

Comment: Do you think if I was to create a branch on the version I have on my home computer (good commit) then I push it to that branch I just git pull from my work computer and delete the branch I don't need everything will be ok right?

Comment: reason I ask is because I can't afford to screw up this version since it is the only version which has hope and has the last good commit and its history.

Comment: if you are creating a branch from the good commit and pushing that as a branch to the repo and then merging that branch back into your master branch that should be fine unless you have conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the right version you want to recover, it will make things easier.

In your local repo, use below commands:

```
git reset --hard <commit sha value>
git push -f
```

**Note:**  if you execute the commands in the local not initialized (not cloned from remote), you should fetch first by `git fetch --all`, and then execute the two commands .

Now the version will go back to the latest as you need both locally and remotely.

Comment: I did try that but it didn't end up working because that sha got deleted in the force push. I was able to fix it however with the suggestion made by the answer I accepted

Comment: It can works. Even the sha is not exist in commit history by force push, but it still exist in git/objects. And if you executed the commands in the local not initialized (not cloned from remote), you should fetch first by `git fetch --all`, then execute the commands, and your branch will reset the the latest version.